# How to plot certain days using Pandas Calendar Heat Map

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter, heatmap

I have a set of data that I want to plot certain dates on the calendar heat map using pandas and calmap.

I tried looking up on pythonhosted.org/calmap/ and all I found on the internet was this example.

```py
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calmap')))
import pandas as pd
import calmap
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

all_days = pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=700, freq='D')
days = np.random.choice(all_days, 500)
events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (15, 10))
calmap.yearplot(events, year=2015, ax=ax)
```

This example plots out random days but I would like plot only certain days on the heat map.

Is there any website I can learn more on the parameters of this?

Answer (score -2):

These links are some of my favorites for charting and plotting.

http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html